# Setting Http Headers in blackberry application

Tags: http, blackberry

I have set the header as c.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US"); in BB app and
i am reading it on server as Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE").
But i am getting a null value.
What may be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The header you are trying to read is [`Accept-Language`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4):

```
c.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US");
```

If you want to use the [`Content-Language`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.12) header, then you could read it with `Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_CONTENT_LANGUAGE")` constant.